# What is mapinfo precision on coordinates

Tags: qgis, mapinfo, oracle-spatial

I have some roads on Mapinfo and looks OK, all nodes seem connected at 0.01 m Zoom.

[image]

If you try to export it to mid/mif you can see the same coordinates `(-63.869036 11.039044)`on all 3 lines.

```
Line -63.869036 11.039044 -63.868923 11.038725
    Pen (1,2,5263440) 
Pline 3
-63.869593 11.040682
-63.869389 11.040049
-63.869036 11.039044
    Pen (1,2,16711680) 
Line -63.869036 11.039044 -63.868698 11.03901
    Pen (1,2,16711680)
```

But in QGis you can see there is a difference and the nodes aren't exactly the same

[image]

The maps are save using oracle spatial. But my guess the problem radicate on MapInfo use some kind of grid of 10x10 cm and snap the nodes there. But still save it with more than 6 decimals in db. And QGis can understand more than the 6 decimals MapInfo use.

So how can I solve this so my MapInfo maps doesnt look broken on QGis.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an explanation on MapInfo node precision. https://web.archive.org/web/20150418133027/www.mapinfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/Focusing-in-on-Spatial-Precision-White-Paper.pdf

I don't know if this has changed with the newer 64-bit MapInfo versions.